# google.auth.exceptions.TransportError when trying to run google cloud vision quickstart guide

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to run the [google cloud vision quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detect-labels-image-client-libraries) but when calling `response = client.label_detection(image=image)` I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:grpc._plugin_wrapping:AuthMetadataPluginCallback "<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 0x7fc1f3f66350>" raised exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 111, in refresh
    self._retrieve_info(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 88, in _retrieve_info
    request, service_account=self._service_account_email
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 234, in get_service_account_info
    return get(request, path, params={"recursive": "true"})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/_metadata.py", line 187, in get
    response,
google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fc1fb046910>)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 90, in __call__
    context, _AuthMetadataPluginCallback(callback_state, callback))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 101, in __call__
    callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 88, in _get_authorization_headers
    self._request, context.method_name, context.service_url, headers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/credentials.py", line 133, in before_request
    self.refresh(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/auth/compute_engine/credentials.py", line 117, in refresh
    six.raise_from(new_exc, caught_exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fc1fb046910>)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     71         try:
---> 72             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     73         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

7 frames
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fc1fb046910>)"
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer vision.googleapis.com:443 {grpc_message:"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: (\"Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\\nb\'\'\", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fc1fb046910>)", grpc_status:14, created_time:"2022-09-13T14:48:30.187999422+00:00"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     72             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     73         except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 74             raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
     75 
     76     return error_remapped_callable

ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ("Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Status: 404 Response:\nb''", <google.auth.transport.requests._Response object at 0x7fc1fb046910>)
```

I'm executing the example code in a google colab, here's my code:

```
#connect to google drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

#download and extract google cloud client
!curl -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-cli-401.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
!tar -xf google-cloud-cli-401.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

#set credentials environment variable
!export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/content/drive/MyDrive/imagelabeling-1663076432940-26cfebd304cf.json

#install and init google cloud
!./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting False --quiet
!./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init

#install google-cloud-vision libraries
!pip install --upgrade google-cloud-vision

#download cat image
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googleapis/python-vision/master/samples/snippets/quickstart/resources/wakeupcat.jpg

#run labeling code
import io
import os

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import vision

# Instantiates a client
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

# The name of the image file to annotate
file_name = os.path.abspath('/content/wakeupcat.jpg')

# Loads the image into memory
with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)

# Performs label detection on the image file
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations

print('Labels:')
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

during `!./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` I select `Re-initialize this configuration [default] with new settings` and then login with my google username by clicking on the weblink and copy-pasting the auth code. After that I'm selecting the testproject I've setup in the console.

I have confirmed that billing is enabled for this testproject. I have also enabled the vision API for this project and I have created a service account for this project with 'Owner' role and have created a json key file, which is located on the mounted google drive path `/content/drive/MyDrive/imagelabeling-1663076432940-26cfebd304cf.json``

Did I miss something?